# Google play services, sign in succeeded but error on create room

Tags: android, libgdx, multiplayer, google-play-services

This is very similar to a problem someone else had on here except that the solution that fixed theirs is not my problem. (Note: I am using libgdx to develop this but I'm pretty sure that has nothing to do with this issue since the signing part is working)

```
@Override
public void startQuickGame() {
    boolean signedIn = getSignedIn();
    System.out.println(signedIn);
     // automatch criteria to invite 1 random automatch opponent.  
    // You can also specify more opponents (up to 3). 
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 4, 0);

    // build the room config:
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();

    // create room:
    aHelper.getGamesClient().createRoom(roomConfig);
}
```

And here is where I check when the room is created.

```
final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10002;
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
    if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        return;
    }
    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = aHelper.getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}
```

The status code I'm getting there is 6 which corresponds to

```
STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED
```

I'm definitely signed in before it creates the room as signedIn is always true.

[image: I have multiplayer enabled on my dev console]

My package name is matching, and I'm even seeing this in my api console.

[image: games.rooms.create]

[image: error messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Misleading Javadoc plus human error.

[image]

I took that second argument to mean the max number of players, not the max number of players to invite, hence you + 3 others.

So here is the culprit in my code =p

```
Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 4, 0);
```

Should be

```
Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 3, 0);
```

And now it works just fine =)

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the room by Auto-Picking a name?  Or by selecting someone in your circles?

I have not published my app in final release (several months of alpha/beta testing, and I'm close :) ), but when I create rooms that I have invited people that are NOT part of the testing group, I get Error 6 (and in fact I have created methods to handle that situation for the release version.. if that same error occurs when a user tries to create a room when released)

If the auto-pick works fine, and you have added the selected people into your testing emails, then the only time I've gotten error 6 would be when the network is having issues (whether on my end or Google's, not sure) but it has been very temporary in nature.

So, I would think ensuring that they are part of your testing group (and may even have to have installed the app, not sure on that part as I haven't tested that out... new test to add!), would be where I would start.

Comment: Yea I'm using auto match with minimum one player max of  four.  I'm the only one working on this do I just have the one account that's part of the testing group but I figured since I set the minimum to one that would be ok.