# GamesStatusCodes, Status 6, STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

---

Hello guys,

I have been trying to implement google play services with LibGDX and am trying to create a Quickgame() where everyone is auto matched. However, on the public void onRoomCreated(int arg0, Room arg1) method, the when i print out the status code, it keeps giving me 6.

I have tried several solutions but to no avail

1. Relinking the game and ensuring the SHA1 code is correct. (Sign in works correctly)
2. Checking my phones network status, it is connected to the internet.

Does anyone perhaps have a solution? Thank you!

```
public class GSGameHelper extends GameHelper implements RoomUpdateListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener,RoomStatusUpdateListener {
    final static String TAG = "ButtonClicker2000";
    static final int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;
    static final int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10002;
    private Activity activity;
    private String mRoomID;
    private MacroHardv2 game;

public GSGameHelper(Activity activity, int clientsToUse) {
    super(activity, clientsToUse);
    this.activity = activity;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void quickGame(){
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

    // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

}

public void initMatch(){
    Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, 1);
    this.activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
}

private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder((RoomUpdateListener) this)
            .setMessageReceivedListener((RealTimeMessageReceivedListener) this)
            .setRoomStatusUpdateListener((RoomStatusUpdateListener) this);
}

public void onActivityResult(int request,int response, Intent data){
    if (request == GSGameHelper.RC_WAITING_ROOM){
        if (response == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED || response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM ){
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoomID);
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            BaseGameUtils.showAlert(activity, "Partida abandonada");
        }else{
            BaseGameUtils.showAlert(activity, "Comenzando partida");
            this.game.multiplayerGameReady();
        }

    }
    else if (request == GSGameHelper.RC_SELECT_PLAYERS){
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }

        // get the invitee list
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

        // get auto-match criteria
        Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
        int minAutoMatchPlayers =
                data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
                data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        Gdx.app.log("J", "Jmin" + minAutoMatchPlayers + " Jmax:" + maxAutoMatchPlayers);
        for (String invitee : invitees){
            Gdx.app.log("L" , invitee);
        }
        if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
            autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                    minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
        } else {
            autoMatchCriteria = null;
        }

        // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
        if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
            roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
        }
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

        // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onJoinedRoom(int arg0, Room arg1) {
    if (arg0 != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Gdx.app.log("R", "Joined FAILED");
    }else{
        Gdx.app.log("R", "Joined Room");
    }


}

@Override
public void onLeftRoom(int arg0, String arg1) {
    BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(activity, "Abandonado partida");
    Gdx.app.log("LEAVE", "Me fui de la Room");

}

@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int arg0, Room arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setGame(MacroHardv2 game){
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int arg0, Room arg1) {
    if (arg0 != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        //BaseGameUtils.showAlert(activity, "Room creation error");
        BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(activity, "Error al crear la partida", "Room creation error " + arg0).show();
        Gdx.app.log("R", "Room Created FAILED");
    }else{
        Gdx.app.log("R", "Room Created");
        mRoomID = arg1.getRoomId();
        Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(getApiClient(), arg1, 2);
        this.activity.startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
    }

}

public void sendPos(float x,float y){
    try{
        byte[] mensaje;
        mensaje = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putFloat(x).putFloat(y).array();
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendUnreliableMessageToOthers(getApiClient(), mensaje, mRoomID);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
    float x, y;
    byte[] b = rtm.getMessageData();
    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    x = bf.getFloat();
    y = bf.getFloat();
    game.updateGameWorld(x,y);
}

@Override
public void onConnectedToRoom(Room arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

@Override
public void onDisconnectedFromRoom(Room arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onP2PConnected(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onP2PDisconnected(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeerDeclined(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeerInvitedToRoom(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeerJoined(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeerLeft(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeersConnected(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPeersDisconnected(Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRoomAutoMatching(Room arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRoomConnecting(Room arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#proguard_issues), you need to check if multiplayer support is enabled for your client ID. You need to enable real-time multiplayer support in the Developer Console. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_multiplayer_support) on how to enable multiplayer support.

This [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902457/google-play-services-sign-in-succeeded-but-error-on-create-room) might also help.

Comment: hmm, i tried the SO ticket link but i didnt understand why changing the matchmaking criteria would solve the problem. I tried it but it didnt work too. I also changed the multiplayer support in the developer console, but it still didnt work. Is there a better way to debug it? Thank you!

Comment: Ever figure out this problem?